# UNION vs DISTINCT in performance

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008, I have a query like so:

```
QUERY A
UNION 
QUERY B
UNION 
QUERY C
```

Will it be slower/faster than putting the result of all 3 queries in say, a temporary table and then `SELECT`ing them with `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the query -- without knowing the complexity of queries A, B or C it's not one that can be answered, so your best bet is to profile and then judge based on that.

**However...**
I'd probably go with a union regardless: a temporary table can be quite expensive, especially as it gets big. Remember with a temporary table, you're explicitly creating extra operations and thus more i/o to stress the disk sub-system out. If you can do a select without resorting to a temporary table, that's always (probably) going to be faster.

There's bound to be an exception (or seven) to this rule, hence you're better off profiling against a realistically large dataset to make sure you get some solid figures to make a suitable decision on.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT and UNION stand for totally different tasks. The first one eliminates, while the second joins result sets. I don't know what you want to do, but it seems you want distinct rows from 3 different queries with joined results. In that case:

```
query A UNION query B......
```

that would be the fastest, depending of course on what you want to do.

Comment: As far as I know UNION automatically does a DISTINCT internally.. UNION ALL, does not apply that DISTINCT to the result set.

Comment: Indeed, a `UNION` both pastes two result sets and eliminates the duplicate rows.  `UNION ALL`, however, only pastes two result sets together, and doesn't do any elimination.  So `DISTINCT` only does one thing; elimination.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used them to rarely to ask this question. But basically UNION is like SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (... UNION ALL...). I'll correct my answer.